# decrease div z-index within ng-repeat dynamially

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem with dynamically setting the z-index within an ng-repeat. Say I have an object array like so in my controller (this is dynamic, so I can add, and remove later).

```
$scope.profiles = [{name: 'name', photo: 'path/to/photo.jpg', age: 30, position: ''}, ....];
```

Now I present this data within my view like so:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="profile in profiles track by $index" data-is-last="{{ $last }}">
    <!-- Profilet Card -->
    <div class="profile-card" data-ng-style="{'z-index': (profiles.length - $index)}"></div>
    <!-- Profile's Contact List  -->
    <div class="profile-contact" data-ng-style="{'z-index':  (profiles.length - $index) }"></div>
</div>
```

Now I need to decrease the z-index within my repeater, however the above won't work as I need the `div` with `class="profile-contact"` to have a z-index lower than the `div` with `class="profile-card"`. Currently they are both the same value.

I tried setting a variable in my Controller and returning it to the view like so:

In the Javascript Controller

```
$scope.zCount = 50;

$scope.setZindex = function () {
  $scope.zCount = $scope.zCount - 1;
  var returnThis = $scope.zCount;
  return returnThis;
};
```

Here is the HTML view

```
<div data-ng-repeat="profile in profiles track by $index" data-is-last="{{ $last }}">
    <!-- Profile Card -->
    <div class="profile-card" data-ng-style="{'z-index': setZindex()}"></div>
    <!-- Profiles's Contacts List  -->
    <div class="profile-contact" data-ng-style="{'z-index':  setZindex() }"></div>
</div>
```

However this created massive `$digest` errors. How should I dynamically set the value of the Z-index so the second div is always lower than the sibling before it?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second approach can't work, as the angular digest loop will run multiple times on your page and with each round your z-indexes will get smaller.

You could simply adapt your original approach like this:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="profile in profiles track by $index" data-is-last="{{ $last }}">
    <!-- Profilet Card -->
    <div class="profile-card" data-ng-style="{'z-index': ((profiles.length - $index)*2)}"></div>
    <!-- Profile's Contact List  -->
    <div class="profile-contact" data-ng-style="{'z-index':  ((profiles.length - $index)*2 - 1) }"></div>
</div>
```

Now each `profile-card` gets a `z-index` twice as high as before while the corresponding `profile-contact` gets an `z-index` which is between the `profile-cards`.

Comment: Brilliant answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this

html

```
data-ng-style="setZindex($index)"
```

js

```
$scope.setZindex = function () {
  $scope.zCount = $scope.zCount - index;
  return {'z-index':$scope.zCount}
};
```

Comment: Won't that just give me the same errors as before? E.g. 'Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!'

Comment: have you try it :) i use a similar code in one table for other reason and that's work

Comment: Yes, I got the same digest errors? However Daniel's answer solves my problem... thanks anyway